# How can I add stars to broom package's tidy() function output?

Tags: r, dataframe, lm, tidyverse, broom

I have been using the broom package's `tidy()` function in R to print my model summaries.

However, the `tidy()` function returns p-values without stars, which makes it a bit weird for many people who are used to seeing stars in model summaries.

Does anyone know a way to add stars to the output?

Answer (score 10):

We can use a convenient function `stars.pval` from `gtools` to do this

```
library(gtools)
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>%
   lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec, .) %>%
   tidy %>%
   mutate(signif = stars.pval(p.value))
#        term  estimate std.error  statistic      p.value signif
#1 (Intercept) 19.746223 5.2520617   3.759709 7.650466e-04    ***
#2          wt -5.047982 0.4839974 -10.429771 2.518948e-11    ***
#3        qsec  0.929198 0.2650173   3.506179 1.499883e-03     **
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not really the purpose of `tidy`. It is used to make tidy data frames from various objects, not to provide additional metrics about those objects.

You could always write a function to generate stars based on p-values and add a column to the data frame generated using `tidy`. For example:

```
make_stars <- function(pval) {
  stars = ""
  if(pval <= 0.001)
    stars = "***"
  if(pval > 0.001 & pval <= 0.01)
    stars = "**"
  if(pval > 0.01 & pval <= 0.05)
    stars = "*"
  if(pval > 0.05 & pval <= 0.1)
     stars = "."
  stars
}
```

Then something like:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec, .) %>% 
  tidy() %>% 
  mutate(signif = sapply(p.value, function(x) make_stars(x)))

         term  estimate std.error  statistic      p.value signif
1 (Intercept) 19.746223 5.2520617   3.759709 7.650466e-04    ***
2          wt -5.047982 0.4839974 -10.429771 2.518948e-11    ***
3        qsec  0.929198 0.2650173   3.506179 1.499883e-03     **
```

Answer (score 1):

As used by the `printCoefmat` function in R, you can also use the `symnum` function from the `stats` package (included in base r):

```r
pv <- c(0.00001, 0.002, 0.02, 0.06, 0.12, 0.99)

stars <- symnum(pv, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
       cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
       symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))

# fetch the stars only
as.character(stars)
#> [1] "***" "**"  "*"   "."   " "   " "

# fetch the legend description
attr(stars, "legend")
#> [1] "0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1"
```

Created on 2018-09-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Or to precisely answer your question, you can use it like so

```r
library(dplyr)

pv <- c(0.00001, 0.002, 0.02, 0.06, 0.12, 0.99)

star_function <- function(x) {
  symnum(x, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
         cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
         symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
}
stars <- star_function(pv)

# fetch the stars only
as.character(stars)
#> [1] "***" "**"  "*"   "."   " "   " "

# fetch the legend description
attr(stars, "legend")
#> [1] "0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1"

mtcars %>%
  stats::lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec, .) %>%
  broom::tidy(.) %>% 
  mutate(sign = as.character(star_function(p.value)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value sign 
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 (Intercept)   19.7       5.25       3.76 7.65e- 4 ***  
#> 2 wt            -5.05      0.484    -10.4  2.52e-11 ***  
#> 3 qsec           0.929     0.265      3.51 1.50e- 3 **
```

Created on 2018-09-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).