# how to save printed data to data frame

Tags: r

How do you save printed information to a data frame? I need to include the * column.

```
ss <- coef(summary(model3))
pv <- ss[,"Pr(>|t|)"]
Signif <- symnum(pv, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
                 cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
                 symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
printCoefmat(ss)
```

Comment: You can find the answer to your question from the link  here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877475/how-can-i-add-stars-to-broom-packages-tidy-function-output

Comment: There's also examples in the help page of `symnum`.